# How to fix ‘net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 201 (Created)’ error in ASP.NET Core C#”

Tags: c#, typescript, asp.net-core

When I post the data to the endpoint I get the error message in the console

> net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 201 (Created)

How do I resolve this?

I tried to post the data to the correct endpoint but the follow line of code is not working.

Here is the typescript:

```
saveOrUpdateOrder() {
  var body = {
    ...this.formData,
    OrderItems: this.orderItems
  };
  return this.http.post(environment.apiURL + '/Order', body);
}
```

Here is the POST: api/Order

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostOrder([FromBody] Order order)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    _context.Orders.Add(order);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtAction("GetOrder", new { id = order.Id }, order);
}
```

The actual result that I'm getting in the console:

> POST http://localhost:52970/api/Order net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 201 (Created).

Comment: Take a look at the following discussion: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19555

Comment: Sorry, did you reach a solution?